# How do I get xdebug/step-debugging working with ddev?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, ddev

I've been working with ddev on my Drupal projects, and now want to use xdebug so I have step-debugging with PhpStorm (or really any IDE would be fine). But I can't seem to get it to stop on breakpoints. I tried to follow the [instructions in ddev docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/step-debugging/) but that doesn't do get me going, and I don't know what to do next. I did:

- Set the 172.28.99.99 IP address as discussed there
- Enabled xdebug using config.yaml `xdebug_enabled: true` and `ddev start` (and checked with phpinfo to see that xdebug was enabled.)
- Put PHPStorm in "listen for debug connections" mode

Comment: Collect xdebug log -- only that way you may see what's happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Debugging xdebug in any setup can be a little trouble, but here are the steps to take:

- First, reread the [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/debugging-profiling/step-debugging/). You may want to read the [troubleshooting docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/debugging-profiling/step-debugging/#troubleshooting-xdebug) rather than this issue, since they're maintained more often.
- Make sure xdebug has been enabled; it's disabled by default for performance reasons. Most people use `ddev xdebug on` to enable it when they want it, and `ddev xdebug off` when they're done with it, but it can also be enabled in `.ddev/config.yaml`.
- Don't assume that some obscure piece of code is being executed and put a breakpoint there. Start by putting a breakpoint at the first executable line in your index.php. Oh-so-many times people think it should be stopping, but their code is not being executed.
- `ddev ssh` into the web container. Can you `ping host.docker.internal` (and get responses)? If you can't, you might have an over-aggressive firewall.
- In PHPStorm, disable the "listen for connections" button so it won't listen. Or just exit PHPStorm.
- `ddev ssh`: Can `telnet host.docker.internal 9003` connect? If it does, you have something else running on port 9003, probably php-fpm. Use `lsof -i :9003 -sTCP:LISTEN` to find out what is there and stop it, or [change the xdebug port and configure PHPStorm to use the new one](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/step-debugging/#using-xdebug-on-a-port-other-than-the-default) . Don't continue until your telnet command does not connect.
- Now click the listen button on PHPStorm to start it listening for connections.
- `ddev ssh` and try the `telnet host.docker.internal 9003` again. It should connect. If not, maybe PHPStorm is not listening, or not configured to listen on port 9003?
- Check to make sure that Xdebug is enabled. You can use `php -i | grep grep Xdebug` inside the container, or use any other technique you want that gives the output of `phpinfo()`, including Drupal's admin/reports/status/php. You should see `with Xdebug <version>, Copyright (c) 2002-202x` and  `php -i | grep "xdebug.remote_enable"` should give you `xdebug.remote_enable: On`.
- Set a breakpoint in the first relevant line of the index.php of your project and then visit the site with a browser. It should stop there.

A note from @heddn: If you want to have xdebug running only for fpm, `phpenmod -s fpm xdebug` for example, instead of running `enable_xdebug`.

A note from @mfrieling: If you use a browser extension like [XDebug Helper](https://github.com/mac-cain13/xdebug-helper-for-chrome) which sets an IDE key, that must be the same as on the server. The used IDE key must be the same on the server, the browser extension/cookie sent and PHPStorm. You can change the IDE key in DDEV by creating a file `.ddev/php/xdebug.ini` with the following two lines (replace `PHPSTORM` with the value you want use:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

Your followups are welcome here!

Comment: Excellent breakdown for debugging! I followed all the steps and was still having issues, it turns out that xdebug doesn't run properly yet on php 7.3 so I stepped my ddev config down to 7.2 and it worked OOTB! Thought that should be documented somewhere :P

Comment: Thanks for the great debug steps. In my case the step with `ping host.docker.internal` failed, and the solution was not an over-aggressive firewall, but this one: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2965#issuecomment-574832076
Using Mac with up to date Docker for Mac, DDEV and PhpStorm versions.

Comment: I had the dreaded permanent "Waiting for connection" display. Solved it by updating from PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4 (it's 2021, baby). Also, changed the xdebug port like described in your 7th bullet. This answer is bookmarked now!

Comment: Thanks @rfay. It seems the readthedocs link is no longer valid.

Comment: Wow @pmagunia that was way, way out of date. You'll be better with DDEV's troubleshooting docs anyway, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/debugging-profiling/step-debugging/#troubleshooting-xdebug - but I edited the URLs and such.

Comment: I had to set path mappings. So on project root -> /var/www/html and web -> /var/www/html/web and web/public -> /var/www/html/web/public

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, had the same problem and adding the file `.ddev/docker-compose.xdebug.yaml` fixed the issue.

However, I am running on a Mac / OSX and found these additional steps worked to discover the IP address of the internal host from inside the container:

1.) Log into the web continaner `ddev ssh`

2.) Run `ping docker.for.mac.localhost`

3.) Set the returned IP address for `host.docker.internal` in the above yaml file.

4.) Remove and start the DDEV.

Also worth mentioning [validating xdebug](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Validating+Your+Debugging+Configuration) in PHPStorm is useful to check the config.

Comment: The docker.for.mac.localhost should be the same as host.docker.internal, it's an older way of Docker providing that address. You should not have had to do any of these things in current versions of Docker for Mac and ddev.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with Macs, as they may have php-fpm running. If it's the case PHP Storm won't find the connection (as it's already taken by php-fpm).

To see if it's the case run:

```
lsof -i :9000 -sTCP:LISTEN
```

if it returns something like php-fpm, then you have this issue

Try closing it (see [PHP-FPM can't be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520433/php-fpm-cant-be-closed) ).

Running it once you have fixed it (potentially restarted your mac) you should see something like this:

```
➜  solrpoc lsof -i :9000 -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND  PID             USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
phpstorm 512 alejandro.moreno  490u  IPv6 0xaf3eef0f3233a83      0t0  TCP *:cslistener (LISTEN)
```

Comment: If php-fpm has been installed and started with homebrew, `brew services stop php`. In 2022, ddev will start using port 9003 instead of 9000 now that both PhpStorm and vscode listen on 9003 in addition to 9000.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I was using a local alias for the site, but Drush was assuming I was using the default [sitename].ddev.site. Since I never hit that domain, it never prompted the zero-configure allow dialog, and thus was never listening to that port with that domain.

I hit the default domain, and opted in when the PHPStorm "Allow incoming connection" dialog, and it worked.