# PHP-FPM can't be closed

Tags: fpm

```sh
  501 25131     1   0  9:31下午 ??         0:00.37 /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
  501 25136 25131   0  9:31下午 ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
  501 25137 25131   0  9:31下午 ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
  501 26377 26220   0 10:32下午 ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn php-fpm
```

I modified php-fpm.conf `daemonize = no`, when restart php-fpm by

```
kill -USR2 'cat /usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.pid'
```

and then I find I can't close php-fpm by

```
kill -9 25131
```

I can see fpm restart automatically through the error log:

```sh
[26-Sep-2018 23:13:43] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[26-Sep-2018 23:13:43] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[26-Sep-2018 23:13:43] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[26-Sep-2018 23:13:43] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[26-Sep-2018 23:13:43] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 26948
[26-Sep-2018 23:13:43] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

It will restart with a new PID, I find no master process and dont know what does `--nodaemonize`  mean.

This problem happened on my macbook just now.

Comment: Not really a programming question (ask server fault). Anyway on recent systems to stop php-fpm we do `systemctl stop php-fpm` (systemd) or `service php-fpm stop` (init). And [this](https://linux.die.net/man/8/php-fpm).

Comment: @RingØ I forgot to say the problem happened on my macbook.

Answer (score 11):

In the dir `~/Library/LaunchAgents` find this file `homebrew.mxcl.php.plist`.

Delete it and restart my mac, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Omg thank you. There were many answers none worked this actually solved it for me